# Dictionary To list issue

Tags: c#, xcode, linq, dictionary

I have the following dictionary I'm filling out with data being parsed in via a third party object.

It looks like this which is in my parsing class:

```
public string beaconMajor;
public string[] beaconValues;
public Dictionary<string, float> valueDictionary = new Dictionary<string, float>();
public string foo = "";

public void DistanceValue(string message)
{

    foo = message.Split (',');

    foreach (string b in foo)
    {
         beaconValues = beacon.Split('_');

        beaconMajor = beaconValues[0];
        string beaconDistance = beaconValues[1];

        if(valueDictionary.ContainsKey(beaconMajor))
        {
            valueDictionary[beaconMajor] = float.Parse(beaconDistance);
        }
        else
        {
            valueDictionary.Add(beaconMajor, float.Parse(beaconDistance));
        }
    }

    if (foo.Contains("-1")) 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Then in another class I'm doing the following with the dictionary, only going to show you the one entry but there are many that look like this:

```
if (foo_class.valueDictionary.ContainsKey ("key"))
{
    beacon1Scale = float.Parse (foo_class.valueDictionary["key"].ToString());
}
```

Now what I'm wanting to do is order this dictionary by its values and not the keys. The keys are constants, but the values change every few seconds. I've tried the following code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> list = foo_class.valueDictionary.ToList();

list.Sort
(delegate(KeyValuePair<string, float> val1, KeyValuePair<string, float> val2)
    {
        return val1.Value.CompareTo(val2.Value);
    }
);

Debug.Log(list);

dictionaryString = list.ToString() + "\n";
```

But when I run this, I get the following message in xCode:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Single]]
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
>   UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) TriangulationScript:Update()

Can someone please inform me the cause of this message?

I'm still looking into getting this dictionary to sort itself via the values, I've even tried using LINQ but this was incompatible with xCode and I was a JIT error message in Xcode as follows:

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable1:GetEnumerator
>   ()' while running with --aot-only.

If anyone knows of any other way to do this, please let me know. I've spent days on this now.

Update

I used the suggested answer below and was given this message in xcode:

> ExecutionEngineException: Attempting to JIT compile method
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2>:GetEnumerator ()' while running with --aot-only.
>
> at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Single]].AddEnumerable
>   (IEnumerable`1 enumerable) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Single]]..ctor
>   (IEnumerable`1 collection) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[KeyValuePair`2] (IEnumerable`1 source)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at TriangulationScript.Update ()
>   [0x00000] in :0

Comment: Rolled back edit as the above codes needs to compile in xCode which is why I can't use LINQ. If Anyone knows a way to do so, please let me know.

Comment: OT: how do you use c# in xcode?

Comment: xCode plug in with Unity. All my C# is done Unity side.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> list = items
                                          .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
                                          .ToList<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();
```

Comment: OrderBy is Linq and I've used that before. Which is what resulted in the JIT message mate.

Comment: Then, try to use some sort algorithm of my github repo. https://github.com/Oscarbralo/Algorithms
But you need to chenge to use them with Dictionaries ;)

Answer (score 0):

`list.ToString()` does not do what you think it does - it looks like you're expecting `list.ToString()` to output the entire list's contents to a string.  Instead it used the default behavior for `object.ToString()` which is to emit the fully qualified type name of the object - which in this case is

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Single]]
```

> I'm still looking into getting this dictionary to sort itself via the values.

A `Dictionary` don't *have* an order - if you want to output the kay/value pairs in a certain order you'll have to specify that order each time you iterate over the list, or store as a list of key/value pairs, which won't have the `Dictionary`-specific methods available (like index lookup)